# Directus sets cookie on admin app origin but I need it on my front end app

Tags: cookies, localhost, setcookie, directus

I have directus API and admin app on localhost and I have frontend React app on localhost:3000. When I try to login via client.login method from React interface directus sets cookie to localhost (its admin app origin). But I need this cookie on localhost:3000 where my actual app located. 
Set cookie header is like that:
directus-test-session=4JCvIJhNxCovLAvCwkSulylc8ZYq1iok4EQ3%3A%3A5b84ad5310ba25a7129ed57448136e13; path=/; expires=Sat, 04-Jan-2020 14:06:49 UTC; HttpOnly

Also google console provides warning like below:
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://directus.test was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

I need to set cookie to localhost:3000. How can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Chrome allows you to set cookies to localhost on a specific port at the time of writing*

As for the warning thrown: we can't set the `SameSite` attribute as that will kill support for cross domain cookies entirely. You can either host your end project on the same (sub)domain as Directus or use the JWT mode for authentication instead. (When using `client.login`, set `mode = 'jwt'`).

We can consider making the cookies `Secure` by default, but that would possibly hinder localhost development, as that requires a HTTPS connection for the cookies to be sent.

* Chrome (and the other browsers) have been updating their cookie policy very frequently lately to fight third party tracking.

Comment: Thank you for your support Rijk. I solved issue with Fiddler. I turned my localhost:3000 adress into fake subdomain of directus origin domain. Cookie mode worked as expected.